# discussion indentation in Posts

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to keep the discussion part of posts indented for readability, without resorting to HTML or similar complications? The "Box" seems to completely hijack whitespace;
maybe there's a less disruptive way to designate code (say, with two periods)?

Comment: By 'box' I meant the whole input area - it apparently reduces all whitespace, like tabs, to a single space, running all commentary together. It would be easier if it maintained tabbing for readability, and used something besides whitespace (4 spaces) for code designation.

Comment: That is not supported in comments. Nor are 4 spaces to indent. Backticks for code do work however. If by "box" you mean the question or answer edit box, then please don't use that for discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since many people, and especially a lot of people (me included) who provide answers here do so regularly and often. It is very useful to have a uniform design for questions and answers.

The advantages of not allowing custom designs in individual threads is that:

- It reduces clutter when someone visits the question from Google or another source.
- It allows experienced users to locate the question itself almost immediately.
- It allows us to jump immediately to code segments, locate when they are needed and missing and ask for them.

A very nice byproduct is that markdown, the templating system is also extremely simple. It provides good clean layout without people having to know how to design and again, it's uniform.

This is why it's used here in Stack Overflow, this is why it's used in many other places where readers need to absorb and manipulate lot of information fast like GitHub. The system allows for people to read questions faster, giving each question more attention and a better chance at an answer.

So, in a line - no. There is no way to indent a post for readability, the reason is because uniformity trumps the ability to make your post more stylish or readable in particular areas, because, in fact, for the 'trained eye' it's less readable.

However you can use:

- Quotes `>` when quoting to signal you're quoting someone, or a referenced body of text.
- Code segments (4 space indents) to signal code.
- Lists to signal an enumeration of things.

Comment: OK, markdown may be much easier than I assumed.